# How to Interpret a normally distributed p-value histogram

Tags: p-value, interpretation, permutation-test

[image: a normal p-value distribution]

The p-values are from permutation tests which generates large number of p-values.I need to do a correction for the cutoff.

Note that Number of True Positives are expected to be very low. so left tail is reasonable. but how do i interpret this ? ( ex How to do FDR for this P-values ?)

I learned about interpreting p-val histogram from this blog, http://varianceexplained.org/statistics/interpreting-pvalue-histogram/
but what I got is way off from any thing explained there.

Comment: I don't understand how this histogram arose and what exactly is being asked here. Vote to close as unclear.